# How to configure Code Runner to use Visual C++ compiler?

Tags: visual-c++

I only have visual c++ installed. Do I need to change the executor map? If so, what is the command?

Comment: Isn't CodeRunner Mac-only? Can you definitely run the VC++ compiler on Mac? Or is there some other Code Runner?

Comment: I meant code runner extension in vscode.

Answer (score 1):

1.)Install the Code Runner Extension
2.)Open your C++ code file in Text Editor, then use shortcut Ctrl+Alt+N, or press F1 and then select/type Run Code, or right click the Text Editor and then click Run Code in context menu, the code will be compiled and run, and the output will be shown in the Output Window.

Moreover, you could update the config in settings.json using different C++ compilers as you want, the default config for C++ is as below:

```
"code-runner.executorMap": {
    "cpp": "g++ $fullFileName && ./a.out"
}
```

Comment: How to change settigns.json to use a different compiler